# java check compatibility of my application

Tags: java, compatibility

I have developed an application in Java, but I don't know exactly which JRE will execute my program.

How can I know what Java's version are able to run my program?

Example:

If my program had some line like this:

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = null;
```

Would it get Java 1.8 or later? Or if my program had some line like this:

```java
List<String> list = null;
```

Would it get Java 1.5 or later?

Comment: No, if a compatible JRE isn't installed, your program will most likely just not work.

Comment: I know, but something I program something and really don't know the final user and I do not know which part of my code belongs to which virtual machine

Comment: Your code does not 'belong to a virtual machine'. Can you try to explain more clearly exactly what you are asking?

Comment: List<String> list = null; this just work with java 1.5 or later I would like know some method to check al my code and get the minimun java jre required to run my code.

Comment: Easiest is to use an IDE and set the java language level for your project. Alternatively, build with the relevant JDK version and/or pass the -source [version] param to javac

Comment: If you developed it in Java X, then it should run on N >= X. You can pass the source version as a parameter, but you can't exactly control which version of Java is being run, unless you have access to the machine itself and install the right version as a dependency and then invoke your code with that version.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on which Java version will be targeted to be used to run your application.

If your target platform is Java8, then your application will not run on Java<8 with invalid class version error.

Generaly Java is mostly backward compatibile (public API at least) so if you develop for JavaN then it will run on JavaN and newer. It is up to you to specify target version.

If you have doubs about client, either force him to update to required minimum version of JRE to match your application requirements, or lower your API target version.